# how to use kubernetes with IBM bluemix containers

Tags: kubernetes, containers, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-kubernetes, iks

I am newbie in Kubernetes. I didn't find option for IBM Bluemix container in your_provider for cluster configuration. (I am referring to this [link](http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/binary_release/)). Cloud you please tell me, Is it possible to integrate Bluemix with Kubernetes or not, If so,what can be a good starting point?

Answer (score 4):

Today it is not feasible to run Kubernetes natively within the Bluemix platform.  We are investigating the ability to support the native API and CLI so please check back for future announcements in this space.